# How to add a secondary window to a document-based app

Tags: objective-c, macos, nswindowcontroller

I want to add a secondary window containing resources that can be dragged and dropped into NSDocuments.

My project contains:

1)  ResourceWindow.xib

2)  ViewController.xib

3)  Main.storyboard

```
@interface AppDelegate ()


@property (nonatomic,strong)NSWindowController* wc;
@property  (nonatomic, weak)NSWindow* resourceWindow;
@property (nonatomic, strong)ViewController* vc;


@end

@implementation AppDelegate

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{

    self.wc = [[NSWindowController alloc]initWithWindowNibName:@"ResourceController.xib"];
    self.resourceWindow = [self.wc window];
    [self.wc showWindow:self];
    self.vc = [[ViewController alloc]initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    [self.vc.view setFrame:[self.resourceWindow.contentView bounds]];
    [self.resourceWindow.contentView addSubview:self.vc.view];
}
```

self.wc.window is nil immediately after allocating and initializing it.

Please set me straight on this.

Thanks

EDIT:

ResourceWindow.xib does not contain a window controller just a window .  Is that the problem?  Is the solution to drag and drop a custom object into the xib file and change it's class to NSWindowController?

Comment: The file owner of ResourceWindow.xib should be the window controller, connected to the window. And "ResourceWindow.xib" ≠ "ResourceController.xib".

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the file name issue pointed to by Willeke, windows are nil until showWindow is called.  Sigh.  I started again by subclassing NSWindowManager and checking add xib file.  Then, set the class of files owner to SourceWindowController and changed the code to:

```
@property (nonatomic,strong)SourceWindowController* wc;
@property  (nonatomic, weak)NSWindow* resourceWindow;


@end

@implementation AppDelegate

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{    
    self.wc = [[SourceWindowController alloc]initWithWindowNibName:@"SourceWindowController"];
    [self.wc showWindow:self.window];
    self.resourceWindow = [self.wc window];
```

Comment: The window is nil until `window` is called. `showWindow` calls `window`. Sender `self.window` in `[self.wc showWindow:self.window]` is weird.